# jQuery live event is not working in iPhone 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-events

I am working on a video player for iPhone and iPad device in which I added a event listener for dynamic content through live event it is working fine on the PC but not working on the iPad and iPhone device any solution for it?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html Althought I should mention this is jquery mobile, not the normal jquery :)

Comment: Which event are you binding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that safari may have a bug with attaching events.

https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/jQuery+live+event+on+iPhone+doesn%27t+work

The article above only mentions click events but I wonder if it could be related?

L